# Drag with interact.JS

Tags: javascript, interact.js

How can I drag an object between two bootstrap columns, with Interact.JS? 
See http://codepen.io/drumiriades/pen/dGrygg.

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">      
                <div class="boardLeft">
                    <p>Left</p>
                    <div class="draggable">
                    <p id="drag-1"> dragg me</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="boardRight">
                    <p>Right</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/ row-->
    </div> <!--/ container-->
</body>
```

I have an object with `ID=drag-1` that is draggable on the left column (`Class= boardLeft`) but I can't drag it to the right column (`Class= boardRight`). How can I drag it to the right column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` of the `.draggable` object must be 1 or greater to see the `.draggable` object on top of the right container.

Additionally, your `restrict` option is set to restrict the `.draggable` component to its parent container only. Removing this option allows you to drag it into the right container.

On top of these couple things - you're referencing elements in your JavaScript that don't exist in your layout (`#grid-snap`, `.dropzone`, and `#yes-drop`)

I've updated the CodePen with the elements that do exist, and now it shows that the item is dropped into the right container... but it changes the content. Not sure if that's what you wanted, but that's what your JavaScript is doing.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yewLdb

Comment: Removing the restrict option will also allow it to be dragged outside of either container (which I don't think is the desired behaviour). I think a better approach would be to make the right container its parent when it is 'dropped' over it

Comment: @OblivionCreations I'm not entirely sure (after looking at Ineteract's documentation) how to restrict the drop to just the right container. I updated my answer with more information that may help the OP, but I'm aware it doesn't provide a complete solution.